# Debugging a simple Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move down a div container with Id( topleft) using java script, but my java script code has a problem. Logically, it should work, can someone check?

HTML code

```
<html>
    <title>Test</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div  id="container">
            <div onclick="start()" id="topleft"></div>
            <div id="topright"></div>
            <div id="bottomleft"></div>
            <div id="bottomright"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
}
#topright, #topleft,#bottomright, #bottomleft {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
}
#bottomright, #bottomleft {
    bottom:0;/*175*/
}
#topright, #topleft {
    top:0; /*175*/
}
#bottomleft, #topleft {
    left:0; /*175*/
}
#bottomright, #topright {
    right:0; /*175*/
}
```

JavaScript code

```
mt=0;
function move(){
    topleft=document.getElementById("topleft");
    for (n=0;n<=175;n++){
        topp=topleft.style.top;
        topp=parseInt(topp);
        topp++
        topleft.style.top=topp+"px"
    }
}

function start(){
    setInterval("move()",1);
}
```

Can anybody rectify it?

Comment: @ Bram Vanroy: Actually, it's really helpful that the OP posted a complete, self-contained example. If it were over-long, of course it would want editing, but it isn't. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Still i don't understand what exactly i should change for this code to work? Sry for bad programming skills ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with that code, I suspect #4 and #7 are causing you the most immediate problem:

1. <s>`setInterval("move()"1);` is a syntax error, and so that would be why it's not running. You need a comma before the `1`:</s> *(you've edited the question to fix this)*

   ```
   setInterval("move()", 1);
   // Comma -----------^
   ```
2. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your `mt`, `n`, `topleft`, and `topp` variables. Always declare your variables, and declare them in the innermost scope in which they make sense.
3. Passing strings into `setInterval` is poor practice; it requires the engine to do an implicit compilation and the scope of that compilation is probably not what you expect it to be (although with your code as quoted — e.g., if `move` really is a global — it would work). Just use the function reference:

   ```
   setInterval(move, 1);
   ```
4. You're using `parseInt` on `topleft.style.top` (indirectly), but the `topleft` element doesn't have any `style` attribute, and therefore `topleft.style.top` is `""`. So you're getting `NaN`, which isn't useful. The `style` property on elements does not reflect CSS, it only reflects what's in the `style` attribute of the element. Look at [`getComputedStyle`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle) (for standards-based browsers) or [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for older IE).
5. It's almost always best to use a radix with `parseInt`, e.g.: `parseInt(topp, 10)` rather than just `parseInt(topp)`.
6. FWIW, if the `setInterval` works, that code will run really, really frequently (though not every millisecond; [the specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) engines should treat values below `4` as being `4`, and in any case it's subject to the implementation and the single JavaScript UI thread not being busy with other things).
7. Making a series of changes to elements in a loop without yielding to the browser won't animate those elements. Instead of looping, remember `n` and move the element just one bit on each call. Each time `move` returns, that gives the browser a chance to update the UI.

Here's an example with the minimal modifications I'd make (doesn't handle older IE's `currentStyle`): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/OkOdoloS/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/OkOdoloS/2/edit)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative
      }
      #topright, #topleft,#bottomright, #bottomleft {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
      }
      #bottomright, #bottomleft {
        bottom:0;/*175*/
      }
      #topright, #topleft {
        top:0; /*175*/
      }
      #bottomleft, #topleft {
        left:0; /*175*/
      }
      #bottomright, #topright {
        right:0; /*175*/
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div  id="container">
      <div id="topleft"></div>
      <div id="topright"></div>
      <div id="bottomleft"></div>
      <div id="bottomright"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      (function() {
        var delay = 10;
        var topleft = document.getElementById("topleft");
        var currentPos = parseInt(getComputedStyle(topleft).top, 10);

        topleft.addEventListener("click", function() {
          // Start
          setTimeout(move, delay);
        });

        function move(){
          if (currentPos <= 175) {
            ++currentPos;
            topleft.style.top = currentPos + "px";
            setTimeout(move, delay);
          }
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- I put the code inside a scoping function to avoid creating globals.
- I put the code at the end, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so all elements exist as of when it runs.
- I used a chained series of `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval` (optionaly, in this case it's really a matter of preference).
- Various things from the list at the beginning of the answer.
- I only make one change per callback, so the browser has time to do the animation.
- I made the delay between animation frames a variable (`delay`) and set it to `10`. You can use whatever value suits you, note #6 on the list above if you use values below `4`.
- I used `addEventListener` to hook up the event rather than using an `onclick` attribute. Using `onclick` attributes in the markup requires that you create global functions, which isn't generally a good idea. (On older versions of IE -- including IE8 -- you'll have to use `attachEvent` instead. Or you can do `topleft.onclick = function() { ... };` but that's fairly limiting [you can only have a single handler].)

Comment: I found this mistake but with comma if i change instead of 1 for example 100 or 1000 the code dosn't work, if you have some time an wish to help me can you give me skype ? ) THX

Comment: @user3033268: I suspect #4 in the edit is your main issue. Good luck,

Comment: I think the problem is in my loop, because the program run's if  instead of loop i have this mt++;
 topleft=document.getElementById("topleft");
 
 topleft.style.top=mt+"px";

Comment: @user3033268: Quite right, a combination of #4 and the new #7.

Comment: what do you mean combination of #4 and new #7?

Comment: @user3033268: I mean the problem you're having is very likely a combination of issue #4 on my list and issue #7 on my list. And indeed, fixing those (and a few other things), it works fine, see the update.

Comment: I have one more question to your code. Your <script><script/> code have 1 function that contains more? or what? because the animation starts onload, but not onclick as i call the function start()

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, I missed you were starting the animation with a click. I've updated the answer to show how to do that without creating global functions.

Comment: I have I think the last question, when we write "var currentPosTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(topleft).top, 10);" the value 10 from this line of code, what it does? Thank you

Comment: @Chris: That tells `parseInt` the radix (number base) that the string is expected to be in. 10 is decimal. 8 is Octal. 16 is hexadecimal. And so on. If you don't supply it, `parseInt` will decide based on the first couple of characters in the string; if you know the radix you're expecting (in this case, decimal), it's best to supply it.

Answer (score -1):

As say T.J. Crowder replace the

```
function start(){
    setInterval("move()"1);
}
```

to

```
function start(){
    setInterval(move, 1);
}
```